# persistent menu in facebook will automatically appear in a thread if the person has been away

Tags: facebook, bots, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I was reading facebook documentation about persistent menu, I see that they mentioned "The menu will automatically appear in a thread if the person has been away for a certain period of time and returns."

[facebook documentation here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/it9g1.png)

However I cannot get that to work, can someone help me with that?

Comment: "cannot get that to work" is not very precise. What part are you actually struggling with?

Answer (score 0):

@ChrisB - The menu never automatically appears in the thread when the person has been away and returns.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, it isn't guaranteed that the menu is updated automatically every time we access. Sometimes it doesn't seem to work somehow. It also might be effected by network condition. Facebook haven't announced such a situation officially at least

But there is no other way to update it forcibly. What we can do is just to hope it works on the all users' phone and, to know there is the case it doesn't work.

I think recently it almost works well though.